# Robot Dan and I

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, knowledge

*Robot Dan, world smartest vacuum cleaner, and I took our packages and fly to trip. We had to took our big pistol, that could shot down a tank. Last time we almost started world war 3, by shooting someone called "Kanady." Lovely!
Andes were our first stop. But we were disappointed by cheese food. It was just farmlands with huge cows, goats and pigs. But that was not all - because we were near north pole, Dan shot big flying leviathan. And he died immediately!
In the end of the day (around 9), we flew back home. This time because of Dan. He had very bad diarrhea. There was propably something in the food. (He had chicken vindaloo.) Next stop: Modern centrum of slow access information - England!*

2nd day:

*"Linearity is the property of a mathematical relationship or function" Dan started to read from wikipedia "which means that it can be graphically represented as a straight line." And that is why we had to leave museum of Ancient Internet. Next stop!
Country we flew last was USA. There was a nice cipher factory. They created (for example) nAES (new Advanced Encryption Standard),  RSA (Rivest, Shamir, Adleman), Diffie–Hellman cipher and new MEOW. That was it. Dan knows 32 cipher languages. That was amazing!*

**What is not Dan's favourite number?**

Hint 1:

> I asked robot: "Dan, can we somehow format this text?" "Yes, you can split our 3032 words by 111. Like this!"

Hint 2:

> Dan works at the moment: 'Bzzzzzz' "Dan is tired. Dan will work only with ten words today. Two per paragraph. Easy!"

Hint 3:

> Because of robots these days do not know how to calculate in decimal system, they won't do any letter shifting, ouch!

Hint 4:

> Solution depends highly on number of words. However first association is too hard. Start with formatting and focus on other lines!

Hint 5:

> You need to find (or actually associate from words) five countries that we were in. Last one is easiest "Country ***" !

Hint 6:

> Day two we were in two countries. We were not in USA, but somehow similar country. Hints has something in common!

Hint 7:

> Numbers counts as one word. If I cross out every 3rd word - I would not change solution ( - "idea", only maybe hints!).

Hint 8:

> After hint seven - If I cross out every 2nd word - I would not touch "solution words." Now only seventy words left!

Hint 9:

> There are always some minor hints around. For first country you may want to search root of the problem. Don't think about third more than five seconds. And for fourth there is a knowledge tag.

Hint 10:

> When we woke up, we bought some beer for the trip. Btw today is Wikipedia pretty ancient. It took our best scientists some time to decode its binary code.

Hint 11:

> Still in the morning we also took some highly explosive semtex against leviathans. We traveled between locations in plane without single stop (so it made straight line). However at the end of 1st day we used teleport for faster travel.

Hint 12:

> Country one: Robot, pistol, "Kanady", beer, semtex + **number of hockey players**
>  Country four: Linearity be, something ancient + **does not directly refer to country, but two islands** (and not names, but something linear)
>  country two+five found by @TuomasK, three found by @Gamow

Comment: Are the typos intentional in the text?

Comment: typos? If something like "at/on/by/than/then" - proly just bugs. If you mean "3032 words" or "Kanady", thats on purpose. Write what edits you want to make, easy.

Comment: If you didn't go to the USA on Day 2, does that mean you also didn't go to England on Day 1?

Comment: Not usa, not England, not Andes. Coutries we were in are part of solution - if you find correct one you will know by hints around it if it is correct one.

Comment: Doesn't this have essentially an infinite amount of answers?  For example, I would guess that Robot Dan's favourite number is NOT 15.

Comment: Presumably, once we have all five countries, that'll point us in the direction of a specific number (so we might end up with "ITISNOTTHIRTEEN" or something)

Comment: @Rauwyn It would be something like "A", and you will figure that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the recent multitude of hints, I think I can finally start taking a swing at this. Partial answer for now.

By following Hints 7 and 8, the story text can be reduced down to

> Seventy words:
>
>  *Robot smartest  and  our  fly We  took  pistol,  shot  tank.  we  world  by  called  Andes  first  we  by  It  farmlands cows pigs.  was  because  near Dan flying he  In  of  around  flew  This  of had  diarrhea.  propably  the  had  Next  centrum access*
>
>  *Linearity  property  mathematical  function  to  wikipedia  that  be  as  line  is  had  museum  Internet  Country  last  There  nice  They  example Advanced  RSA  Adleman  and  That  Dan  cipher  was*

The other hints suggest that

> Only ten of those words are needed, six from the first paragraph and four from the second paragraph, with each pair of words corresponding to one of the countries that Robot Dan visited.

**UPDATE:** @TuomasK found the ten words:

> If you take the first word, and then every seventh word (every 21st word of the original text), you get these pairs:
>
>  Robot pistol Andes pigs In diarrhea
>  Linearity be Country RSA

These correspond to:

> **Robot pistol**: Czech Republic (found by @Gamow, see comments for explanation)
>  **Andes pigs**: Guinea (Guinea pigs; found by @TuomasK)
>  **In diarrhea**: India ("**In dia**rrhea"; found by @Gamow)
>  **Linearity be**: Greece (Linear B script, the earliest known form of Greek language - found by @Gamow)
>  **Country RSA**: South Africa (self-explanatory; found by @TuomasK)

Finally, here is how to get a number from that...

> Hint 11 says: "We traveled between locations in plane without single stop (so it made straight line). However at the end of 1st day we used teleport for faster travel."
>
>  If you connect Czech Republic to Guinea by a straight line on the map,
>  and then continue the line from Guinea to India,
>  and then teleport to Greece,
>  and finally draw a straight line from Greece to South Africa,
>  then you have drawn the segments of the digit **4**.

Comment: i would write if you have correct countries. Next hint tomorrow. For Russia i would write vodka, not beer. For kiribati proly something about Date or that it is on all four hemispheres, not ancient.

Comment: "Linearity be" refers to the "Linear B scripts", an ancient body of scripts from the Mycenaean culture, that have been found on the Peloponnese and on Crete. Hence the country should be **Greece**.

Comment: Oh wow, good call! I read about those like an hour ago, and somehow didn't make the connection.

Comment: My guess for country #1 would be Czechoslovakia. **Semtex** has been developed there; Czech **beer** is famous all over the world; they have a strong ice **hockey** team; the Czech writer Karel Čapek invented the word **robot**; the connection to "pistol" is not clear to me.

Comment: That's another good call. "Beer" and "hockey" were what threw me off-track, I didn't know Czech beer/hockey were that famous. I'll add "Czech Republic" and then try and figure out where to get the number from.

Comment: Last part should be easy. So next hint tomorrow, in meantime you can look at hint 11. Btw: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_beer_consumption_per_capita and https://www.statista.com/statistics/282349/number-of-registered-ice-hockey-by-country/
and try google: Robot Pistol Semtex

Comment: Probably doesn't help that most of my work on this puzzle has been done while I'm at work :P

Comment: @F1Krazy Work?... guess where I am? :) And I'm sorry I made it so hard, i didn't wanted to last 10 mins.... but 1 month really wasn't intended.

Comment: It's okay, I think I have a theory now...

Comment: @Gamow And if you change base(like dec/hex/bin), suddenly Dan wasn't that bad in counting… I wanted to ask what is his favourite number, but actually if he use that base, it can't be… so for example  "32 cipher languages" means "11 official languages" in RSA. But that was just bonus.

Comment: Agh! I was just editing in the final answer and was just about to hit "Save" when something came up, and by the time I'd finished @Gamow had already edited it in! Nice work, though! Glad we got there in the end.

Answer (score 5):

This is very partial answer too, but I got some countries!
Made with the great help of @F1Krazy's answer!

> If the text reduced to seventy words, and then only 7th word is picked, we get:
>
>  Robot pistol Andes pigs In diarrhea
>  Linearity be Country RSA

And there we get the countries

> **Robot pistol:** I'm not any kind of sure about this... Israeli company General Robotics have made a combat robots with a pistol attached. So, country is **Israel**
>  **Andes pigs:** Guinea Pigs originally lived in Andes, so next country is **Guinea**
>  **In diarrhea:** This might be some developing country?
>  **Linearity be:** I don't have any idea what this could be!
>  **Country RSA:** RSA means **Republic of South Africa**
>
> Hint 5: *Last one is easiest "Country ***"* makes this seem quite correct

But I don't have any idea how any number could be made from these

Comment: Correct words, 1st country not Israel - hint 4. Also it is not every "7th" or from original text every "21st", but always first word of "21 sequence" which makes it too hard :/. Next hint for part 2 in … 20 hours i guess. But if you find something more, i will wait.

Comment: 1. The clue "In diarrhea" starts with the five letter word "India". 2. "Linearity be" might refer to Chile, which is the most linear country (between mountains and ocean) I know.

Comment: @Gamow not Chile -> hint 10